# How to remove shapes that cause a problem upon reprojection from a geopandas dataframe?

Tags: python, geopandas, proj

In [this](https://geopandas.org/projections.html#re-projecting) `geopandas` example, the Antarctica land mass is dropped from the `GeoDataFrame` before reprojecting to the Mercator projection, in order to prevent problem with shapes containing a pole (which would become infinitely large).

I was wondering, if it is possible to find a more robust reprojection method, so that the dataframe does not need to be manually adjusted. Especially since I'm working with a dataset that does not have a separate row for Antarctica:

[image]

I have two ideas:

## 1. Use information about the destination `crs`

On the [epsg website](https://epsg.io/3395) for example, the 'Area of use' is shown:

[image]

We could use it to prepare the data before the reprojection: drop any shapes that extend further South than -80 deg, or alternatively intersect it with a `shapely Polygon` that describes the area of use of the destination crs, in terms of the source crs - in this case the standard `epsg:4326` so `Polygon([(-180,-80), (-180,84), ...])`.

**Issue with this approach**: I'm not sure, if this area of use information is programmatically accessible from somewhere for any `crs`, e.g. from the `GeoDataFrame` object.

## 2. Fix in post

*Just do it*, and pick out the erroneously reprojcted parts later. In my current case, for example, the reprojected geodataframe `gdf_merc = gdf.to_crs(epsg=3395)` does have errors...

[image]

...but by searching for the `inf` word in the string representation of the geometry, I can find the offending `Polygon` within the `MultiPolygon`...

```
In [360]: for i, polygon in enumerate(gdf_merc.geometry[0]):
   ...:     if 'inf' in str(polygon): 
   ...:         print(i)
  
0
```

...and just remove it:

[image]

**Issue with this approach**: seems elaborate and I'd prefer to prevent any problems from appearing in the first place.

Any thoughts on how to fix either of these methods, or is there a third way?

One remark: I'm interested in the general case, where *any* crs could be reprojected to, so I don't want to preemptively remove Antarctica ("just in case"), as other projections might be perfectly fine with it, and, more importantly, they might have other problem areas.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option 1 is likely the best shot in here. Latest GeoPandas uses pyproj.CRS to store CRS data, from which you can easily extract bounds of the projection.

To extract it from df:

```
import geopandas as gpd
df = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('nybb'))
df.crs.area_of_use.bounds
```

To get it from target CRS using pyproj directly:

```
import pyproj
crs = pyproj.CRS.from_epsg(3395)
crs.area_of_use.bounds
```

Then you can use built-in `geopandas.clip` to clip your data.

```
from shapely.geometry import box

df = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
crs = pyproj.CRS.from_epsg(3395)
bounds = crs.area_of_use.bounds
clipped = gpd.clip(df, box(*bounds))
clipped.to_crs(crs).plot()
```

[image: result]

Comment: Ah that's great! I had noticed that the `GeoDataFrame.crs` property only stores the information as a string - but that's because I specified is as such when instantiating the dataframe. If I pass the `crs` as a `pyproj.CRS` object, all this information is available from the dataframe property as well. I'll look into it, many thanks!

Comment: `GeoDataFrame.crs` does not store it as string anymore, that was deprecated. I'd recommend updating to 0.7.0 if you haven't done so.

Comment: It seems the `gpd.clip` method has some problems (I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1363)) and as a workaround I'd like to use something else. I was thinking about `gpd.overlay`, but that only works with `Polygon`s, or `maskdf.contains`, but that only works with `Point`s. If you happen to have a suggestion, please do share it :)

Comment: `gpd.overlay` works with all geometry types since 0.7.0.

Comment: Ah in that case, the docs are still off... I suppose I could create a branch and pull request for it, or is there a faster way for such issues?

Comment: Branch and PR is the fastest way. I see that docstring is not updated.